# Android WebView display a blank page after I login

Tags: android, webview

I'm trying to load a web application in `WebView` but I've encounter some problem.

The web application that I was trying to load was a login page and I am going to login to it.

Here is where the problem start, I have no problem loading the 1st page but after I login and it should be showing the page after I login but all I can see was a blank page, I've checked on the login log that my account was logged in but there was nothing on the `WebView`.

Here's my code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

            view.loadUrl(url);
            return false;
        }
    });

    webView.loadUrl(url);

}
```

I have tried it using `WebChromeClient` and it was able to load without problem but I want it to load inside `WebView` and not open another browser.
Anyone have any idea on why this is happening?

Comment: can you post the link you are trying to load?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this sample,

> MainActivity.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Window;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private WebView webview;
private static final String TAG = "Main";
private ProgressDialog progressBar;  

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

     setContentView(R.layout.main);

    webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);

    WebSettings settings = webview.getSettings();
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);

    final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();

    progressBar = ProgressDialog.show(Main.this, "WebView Example", "Loading...");

    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Processing webview url click...");
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Finished loading URL: " +url);
            if (progressBar.isShowing()) {
                progressBar.dismiss();
            }
        }

        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + description);
            Toast.makeText(activity, "Oh no! " + description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            alertDialog.setTitle("Error");
            alertDialog.setMessage(description);
            alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    return;
                }
            });
            alertDialog.show();
        }
    });
    webview.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
}
}
```

> main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<WebView android:id="+@id/webview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

> manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

This may helps you.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I works, wondering why the previous code didn't work, is it because of the layout?

Answer (score 0):

use this to load any url that you are willing to open into your web view xml

```
    String url = "URL";
    if (url != null){
        webView.loadUrl(url);
    }else{
        String content = getIntent().getStringExtra(CONTENT_EXTRA);
        webView.loadData(content, "text/html", null);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check your code with different URLs because there is no need to override `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` method to load the url again on login click.